# UIWebView Zoom Level

Tags: uiwebview, iphone

I have to check the zoom level of UIWebView. And set its maximum level to certain Level. I have tried this code but found no success

*edited post to include code formatting*

```
UIScrollView *sRouteView = [[testWebView subviews] objectAtIndex:0];
    sRouteView.delegate = self;
    sRouteView.minimumZoomScale = 1.0;
    sRouteView.maximumZoomScale = 2.0;
    sRouteView.zoomScale = sRouteView.minimumZoomScale;
```

I am unable to set maximum zoom level of UIWebView

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had the same problem and found the solution from Vocaro's post to solve the problem!

"Add the following meta tag to your HTML document's head:

```
<meta name='viewport' content='initial-scale=1.0,maximum-scale=10.0'/>"
```

so basically for you

```
"<meta name='viewport' content='initial-scale=1.0,minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=2.0'/>"
```

should do the trick.

Documents
https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariHTMLRef/Articles/MetaTags.html

Comment: And what if I just display a File in an UIWebView?

Comment: I know this comment is very late, but I actually have the same question as @MartinSchilliger. How to manage a small minimumzoomscale when not displaying a webpage, but just a file in a UIWebView, like a large image?

Comment: I once thought about injecting javascript in the UIWebView, but never tested this. Maybe that is a possibility? Or create an HTML file with the large image inside?